# Authorize.net PHP - How to use the CIM to do monthly payments?

Tags: php, xml, authorize.net

I have seen various libraries in PHP for the Authorize.net Customer Information Manager, but I haven't seen how you can manage how often or make automated monthly or timed payment.

Is this possible? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running linux server, you can use cron.
Cron is a system process that runs the jobs you put it, these jobs give you the job by writing to it in a text file.

To read more about cron, you can read here: http://troy.jdmz.net/cron/

And then you can run the php script with cron. Here is a article that explains how to do this: http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/

---

If you use Windows, I recommend you to use Windows Task Scheduler.
It is also possible to use [Cron in Windows](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/) too, but there is a lot of extra work, so I personally recommend using the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm) if you use Windows server.